# urlEncode in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

How get **`Mage::helper('core')->urlEncode`** in Magento 2?

Answer (score 2):

Try following way:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Url\EncoderInterface $encoder
) {
    $this->encoder = $encoder;
}
```

Now

```
$this->encoder->encode($url);
```